# TBB performs bad on AMD?

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, intel, tbb, amd-processor

I was recently working on performance profiling a library which used TBB to achieve parallelism.
[I cannot report the library and the readings out here]
After a few tests, I realized the performance of the application on AMD processors was slower than that of Intel processors.
However, I don't have a setup where I have comparable processors (same clock speeds for both processors).

I was just wondering is anybody has had the same experience and is TBB optimized to perform really good on Intel processors as compared to corresponding AMD processors.

Comment: Are you sure it's only TBB and not everything else as well? Unless you have the one the newer Zen AMD processors, they're all gonna be "slow" compared to the Intel ones.

Comment: TBB does nothing processor-specific for regular CPUs. All the code is open-source, you can check yourself.